# Mobile click function not closing menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've built a custom menu using Bootstrap collapse and a list of links within an expanding div. Most of the links are to anchors within the page. When you click a link, the menu closes. Everything works perfectly on a desktop, but on mobile the menu does not close.

I'm pulling my hair out... from what I understand, Safari mobile does consider links to be interactive, but divs are not... So maybe my problem is that the menu is within a div? Or maybe it's my js... Any ideas?

```
<div class="collapse" id="expandmenu">
  <div class="well">
        <div class="container">
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle2 pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" href="#expandmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" style="float:right; padding:16px 5px 17px 0px; color:#333;"><p class="explore" style="font-size:0.8em; color:#333;">Close </p>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:1.1em;"></span>
</button>
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-12 hidden-xs" style="text-align:center; margin-top:0px; color:#333;">



            </div>
                 </div>

    <div class="row">

         <ul class="txt-ctr" style="padding-left:0px;">
            <a href="#passwordstationbenefits"><li class="menubutton"><span>Benefits</span></li></a>
            <a href="#overview"><li class="menubutton">Overview</li></a>
            <a href="#design"><li class="menubutton"><span>Features</span></li></a>
            <a href="#reporting"><li class="menubutton"><span>Reports</span></li></a>
            <a href="#security"><li class="menubutton"><span>Security</span></li></a>
            <a href="#helpdesk"><li class="menubutton"><span>Help Desk</span></li></a>
            <a href="#appsupport"><li class="menubutton"><span>Apps</span></li></a>
            <a href="#architecture"><li class="menubutton"><span>Architecture</span></li></a>
            <a href="#languages"><li class="menubutton"><span>Languages</span></li></a>
            <a href="#ticketing"><li class="menubutton"><span>Ticketing</span></li></a>
            <a href="#testimonials"><li class="menubutton"><span>Testimonials</span></li></a>
            <a href="/products/identity-management/password-management/password-station/demo/"><li class="menubutton"><span>Demo</span></li></a>
            <a href="#resources"><li class="menubutton"><span>Resources</span></li></a>
             <a href="#payingtwice"><li class="menubutton"><span>True Cost</span></li></a>
            <a href="/pricing"><li class="menubutton"><span>Get Pricing</span></li></a>

                </ul>

</div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my js:

```
$('#expandmenu a').click(function(){
  $("#expandmenu button").click();
});
```

Comment: Do you have css for this HTML and jQuery code?

Comment: I think you want to `trigger` the `click` with `$('#expandmenu a').click(function(){
  $("#expandmenu button").trigger('click');
});`

Comment: yeah.. it's a fully-functioning site. I'm not using mobile jquery

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Nice idea but that didn't work...

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this.. I mean a problem demo with jsfiddle.net?